# Understanding of DATEDIFF() function in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datediff

```
select DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()) as date
```

when I execute the query I got answer as 1407 but I am unable to get in which format the answer is in, can anyone explian

Comment: I assume this is SQL Server? But I shouldn't have to assume. Please [edit] and put an appropriate tag in for your database product. The datetime functions differ between products.

Comment: Here 0 means the year '1900-01-01' SELECT DATEDIFF(M,'1900-01-01','2017-04-21') AS DATE

Comment: For reference, when I asked you to edit and add an appropriate tag, `a_horse_with_no_name`s edit was what I was asking for. When we talk about tags, we *mean* tags. Not titles. See [Should questions include "tags" in their titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) for more information

Answer (score 4):

[`DATEDIFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql) takes three parameters - the `datepart` that describes what units you want the result to be in and two dates.

In your case, you're passing a value of `0` as the second argument, which gets implicitly converted to the [`datetime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql) `1900-01-01T00:00:00.000`.

There are currently 1407 months between 1st January 1900 and today.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score -1):

You set the format with first param, in your case months

possible values are listed here:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp

And as shown in the example on w3, you can also use the name of the format, i.e.
select DATEDIFF(month,0,GETDATE()) as date

Comment: May I ask why the downvote??? Asker explicitely asked for the format, explained the format...

Answer (score -1):

Your output 1407. so from 1900 to 2017 we have totally 1407 months.because you using the parameter as m